# Shared library in WebSphere

Tags: websphere

I am facing an issue in WebSphere. I created a shared library containing some properties files.

I have 3 profiles and in every profile I have deployed one application. In one profile I can associate the shared library with the application, however in the others 2 profiles I cannot.

There are no errors being shown.

If any one has faced the same issue or has any ideas, please share with me. I am new to WebSphere application Server.

Comment: Can you please elaborate? What are the exact steps your are doing? I hope you are using separate server instances for separate profiles, that's the basic idea of profiles in WAS.

Comment: I installed WAS express v8 in one server. Then I created 3 profiles in same server. After that I created shared library in every profile and deployed one application. Thanks Sampada Wagde for your reply

Comment: Ok. So you mean there is one EAR which you are referencing via 3 different places?